# Resharper - prefer code style with backing field

Tags: c#, resharper

I prefer this:
        private string _indeks;
        public string Indeks
        {
            get => _indeks;
            set => _indeks = value;
        }

Instead of:
       public string Indeks { get; set; }

But I haven't found a way to enforce that code style in Resharper in "Code Cleanup"?

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: They are doing completely different things

Comment: You are right. I have updated my question.

Comment: In code cleanup menu uncheck `Use auto-property, if possible`

Comment: My question was not precise to say the least. But I do prefer the backing field and cannot get Resharper to enforce that on "Ctrl Alt F"